# Best way to store attribute data in scipy sparse matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, graph-theory

I want to create a scipy `csr_matrix` to represent a sparse graph. For each edge, along with the weight, I want to define several "attributes." One of the attributes will be accessed directly after the weight. The others are less important and will be accessed infrequently.  What is the best/ most efficient way to do this? Do scipy matrices accept non-numbers as entries?

**Example**:

Say I had a sparse matrix `m` represented by arrays (values are weights):

```
[[  0.49850701   0.27           0.        ]
 [  0.22479665   33.            3.        ]
 [  0.           10.            0.        ]]
```

I want to store additional data for each entry (x, y). For example, let's say I wanted to store "lifespan" and "name" attributes.

The lifespan attributes would be in a matrix like this:

```
[[  8.           10.           0.        ]
 [  0.9          4.            3.2       ]
 [  0.           4.3           0.        ]]
```

The name attributes would be in a matrix like this:

```
[[  'Bob'         'Kevin'      0.        ]
 [  'Gary'        'Joe'        'Sally'       ]
 [  0.            'Ralph'      0.        ]]
```

What is the best way to do this? Should I have a separate matrix for each attribute, a matrix for the weight and lifespan and a dict keyed by coordinate tuple for all other attributes, a matrix with list or dict entries, or a matrix for weight and a dict for all the other ones?

Comment: A `csr_matrix` is intended to work with simple numeric values.  The fast calculation methods (e.g matrix multiplication) are compiled for integers and floats.  You may be able to create a matrix with strings as values, but you'll soon hit an error of some sort.

Comment: Do you think a `dok_matrix` or `lil_matrix` would work?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the matrix after creating?  A `dok` format matrix is a subclassed dictionary, one where the keys are the (row,col) indexing tuples.  I can make a 'blank' `lil` with a string `dtype`, but I don't know if I can do much with it.  A lot of conversion go by way of `coo` format.  But `coo` format, on display, tries to add duplicate entries.  That won't work for strings or more complex dtypes.